# Utility function that uses the store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-typescript

I am working with react and I need to create a utility function that uses a parameter from the redux store.

What is the correct way to implement the function?

TIA

Ill give my case as an example:
I need a function the receives a zonedTimeOffset from the redux store and return UTC time with the offset (the zoned time).
I will use this function from various components throughout my App

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to access the store?

Comment: yes. accessing the store isn't the problem here.
I understand that for accessing the store the function needs to be implemented in the FC. 
but I dont want to return a JSX I just need the utility function

Comment: @sm3sher
 added an example to the question

Comment: Are you using React Redux? If so, are you using hooks?

Comment: I am using react redux. by hooks are you mean useSelector?
If so the answer is yes.
The question is more where should I implement this function because it is not a component and it cannot stand alone (cause it needs the redux store)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using React Redux's `useSelector` to access the store, you can write a custom hook that calls it:

```
function useTimeZone(date: Date) {
  const zonedTimeOffset = useSelector(state => state.zonedTimeOffset)
  return new Date(date.getDate() + zonedTimeOffset)
}
```

Then you can call `useTimeZone` in any component (or any other custom hook) instead of `useSelector`:

```
const dateWithTimeZone = useTimeZone(new Date())
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I put this function on its own? if it is using hooks it needs to be in a function component...

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be in a function component, as long as it's a custom hook following the rules of hooks.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this by using the useSelector in the FC that calls the utility function and pass into the utility function the zoned Offset.
Thank you all for your help